# Items of list are not coming in proper position in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm making an app in which I need a listview to show lists of task. It's a location based reminder app. But in the list view, whenever I add an item(Task) to the list, it is coming at the bottom. 
I mean, I want the first item to be added at the top of list, but it is coming at the bottom. So, any help with this?

Here's how the list is coming :

```
list:




first item 
second item
```

Here's how i want it:

```
list:
first item 
second item


..
```

Here is my code for setting up the adapter and listview:

```
    package com.example.fsdf;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Second extends ActionBarActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase mydatabase;
    ListView lv;
    int CheckedItem;
    private Button button;
    private Button button2;
    double lat[] = new double[100];
    double longt[] = new double[100];
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("seproject", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from Store", null);

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            do {
                String s= cursor.getString(0);

                list.add(cursor.getString(0));

                lat[i] = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1));
                longt[i++] = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2));


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            mydatabase.close();

        }
 Collections.reverse(list);  //Kept this here. It worked. 
        adapter  = new marrayadapter(this,list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setItemChecked(0, true);
        CheckedItem = 0;

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                CheckedItem = (position);

            }


        });


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              try {

                  mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("seproject", 0, null);

                  mydatabase.delete("Store", "Job" + "='" + list.get(CheckedItem) + "'", null);
                  Toast.makeText(Second.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 mydatabase.close();
                 /* Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, Second.class);
                  startActivity(i);
                  finish(); Replaced with following*/

                  list.remove(CheckedItem);
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                  }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(Second.this,"No tasks to delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }



            }
        });
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("seproject", 0, null);
                mydatabase.delete("Store", "Job" + "='" + list.get(CheckedItem) + "'", null);
                Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, Edit.class);
                i.putExtra("job", list.get(CheckedItem));
                i.putExtra("lat", lat[CheckedItem]);
                i.putExtra("longt", longt[CheckedItem]);
                startActivity(i);
                mydatabase.close();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_add:
                Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
           /* if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
             */
    }
}
```

Code for custom adapter (marrayadapter.java) :

```
    package com.example.fsdf;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class marrayadapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    public marrayadapter(Context context, ArrayList list) {
        super(context,R.layout.marrayadapter, list);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater amansinflater= LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
       View customView = convertView; //changed this and added if condition
    if(customView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater amansinflater= LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        customView = amansinflater.inflate(R.layout.marrayadapter, parent, false);
    }            String singleTask=getItem(position).toString();
        System.out.println("Here lies :   " + singleTask);
        TextView rowtext = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext);

        rowtext.setText(singleTask);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you want to do?

Comment: I want the list to come in order in listview.

Comment: I mean, the first item added should come at the top of list, but it is coming at the bottom.

Comment: Only one solution used `Custom Adapter`

Comment: I have used custom adapter. (see: "marrayadapter" in code).

Comment: Ok then where is `marrayadapter` code?

Comment: your answer is combination of both `@Krishna V` and `@fida1989`. When you get a list of items 1. reverse and set to adapter (@fida1989) and 2. for every new item add to the top of the list (@Krishna V).

Comment: @MD updated, please see.

Comment: @bharat I will try that. brb.

Comment: @bharat no man, it's not showing the list in listview in the way i want.

Comment: `Collections.reverse(list);` add this line after you are reading data from the database. means before this line   `adapter  = new marrayadapter(this,list);`

Comment: @bharat I tried that. No changes. Can you please check the "marrayadapter" code? I think there's something wrong in that. Any help would be great!

Comment: @MD now, any solutions?

Comment: @AmanB. You just do   `return items.get(items.size() - 1 - position);` in `getItem(......)`

Comment: give another try.. if are maintaining row id (autoincrement) then sort according to that. any other column which which gives the order you need.

Comment: @MD nope that didn't worked, sorry.

Comment: @bharat thanks for all the help dude. I changed the position of `Collections.reverse()` to where you said. Made a change to marrayadapter and it worked. Now the list items are coming correctly. Thanks a ton. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Collections.reverse` function over `list` just before setting adapter:

```
Collections.reverse(list);  
adapter  = new marrayadapter(this,list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: See my updated question please. Sorry for not being clear, I'm a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the list item at 0th index, `list.add(0, cursor.getString(0));`

Comment: See my updated question please. Sorry for not being clear, I'm a newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = this.list.getFirstVisiblePosition() + list.size();
View v = this.list.getChildAt(list.getHeaderViewsCount());
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();         

this.adapter.AddRangeToTop(comments);
this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    

this.list.setSelectionFromTop(index, top)
```

Try this..

Comment: See my updated question please. Sorry for not being clear, I'm a newbie here.